# absolutely continuous ($\sigma$-) finite measures

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity, radon-nikodym

I got two questions:

1. If I have two measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ with $\nu << \mu$ and we know that $\nu$ is (i) finite (e.g. a probability measure) or (ii) $\sigma$-finite. Can we draw any conclusion about $\mu$ in terms of it being also finite or $\sigma$ finite?
2. My other question is the following: Given a probability measure $Q$ on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$ and a dominating measure $\mu$, then we have the Radon-Nikodym derivative $q=dQ/d\mu$. In a book I am reading I found that $Q(\{x\in \mathcal{X}: q(x)>0\})=1$. Why does this hold? Is it necessary that $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite here?

Answer (score 1):

1. No we cannot conclude from $\nu << \mu$ that $\mu$ is finite/$\sigma$-finite from $\nu$ finite. For example, let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and for an $\mu-$integrable $f$ with $f>0$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f d\mu = 1$, let $\nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu$. The $\mu$ is not finite, but $\nu$ is, and $\nu << \mu$.

The only examples I'm aware of of non-$\sigma$-finite measures are on the pathological side, but it is evident that we can come up with silly counter examples here too. For example, we might let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\nu(A)=0$ for all $A$ (trivial measure). Then $\nu << \mu$, but $\mu$ is not $\sigma-$finite.

2. Let $A = \{ q(x) > 0\}$, then $Q(A) = \int_A q(x)d\mu$. But we must also have since $Q$ is a probability measure that, $1=Q(\mathcal{X})=Q(A)+ Q(A^c)$.

Notice that we must have that $Q(A^c) = \int_{A^c} q(x)d\mu = 0$. $A^c = \{q(x)\le 0\}$. Let $B_n = \{ q(x)\le -1/n\}$. Then we must have $\mu(B_n)=0$, since if $\mu(B_n)>0$,
$$Q(B_n)= \int_{B_n}q(x)d\mu(x) \le-\mu(B_n)/n <0,$$ contradicting the positivity of $Q$. Since $B= \{q(x)<0\}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, $0\le \mu(B)  \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n) = 0$. Therefore $Q(B)=0$, and since $A^c/B=\{q=0\}$, $Q(A^c)= Q(B)+ Q(A^c/B)= 0+ \int_{\{q=0\}}q(x)d\mu(x)=0$.

Therefore $Q(A)=1$.

Comment: thanks and do we need in 2) that mu is sigma finite?

Comment: @guest1 No problem! Yes we need sigma finite here only insofar as that is what is required for Radon-Nikodym. If in general we would have that there is a probability measure $Q$ so that $Q(A) = \int_A q(x)d\mu(x)$, then we would have by this argument that $Q(\{ q(x)> 0 \})=1$. I.e. it is not special that $q$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: thank you. Why is the complement of A a nullset?

Comment: I added some details for that to the solution!

Comment: why can q(x) be smaller than 0? Isnt a density always non-negative?

Comment: I think in your proof, when $\mu(B_n)>0$, the contradiction doesnt work. I.e., if we had $\mu(B_n)=0$ then $Q(B_n)$ is still smaller than that which means $Q(B_n)$ would still be negative which is still a contradition.

Comment: I think you must be careful that $Q << \mu$ does not mean $Q(A)< \mu(A)$ for any $A$. It only implies that when $\mu(A)=0$, then $Q(A)=0$. In fact we could have $Q<<\mu$ but $Q(A)\ge \mu(A)$ for all $A$. The argument looks to be sound otherwise.

Comment: So but in the sets Bn you assum q(x) to be negative which is impossible as it is a density, which is non-negative. I.e., the set Bn would just be empty then

Comment: And I mean in the way how you define Bn the inequality will always hold, i.e, that $Q(B_n) < -\mu(B_n)/n$ and that has nothing to do with the absolute continuity but with the way how you define the set Bn. And since this is a strict inequality, it doesnt matter if $\mu(B_n)$ is assumed to be positive or zero - $Q(B_n)$ will always be smaller than zero

Comment: I modified the solution slightly to so that $B_n = \{q \le 1/n\}$, although the solution is still OK anyway, since if $\mu(B_n)=0$ then $Q(B_n)=0$ follows from the first line. I assume here that we are not taking for granted that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is non-negative. In fact that does not have to be so: basically what we are showing here is that the R-N derivative (density) must be $\mu/Q$ almost everywhere positive when $Q$ is a positive measure.  If you are willing to assume that $Q(\{q \ge 0\})=1$, then the result follows immediately since $Q(\{q=0\}) = \int_{\{q=0\}} q d\mu =0$.

Comment: hi why is the radon nikodym derivative not necessarily non-negative (given we have two sigma finite non-negative measures)?

Comment: It is only defined up to almost everywhere equivalence, so it could be negative on a null set. The proof given in the answer shows why.

Comment: just a remark, in your solution you still have $B_n = \{q \leq -1/n \}$ but in your comment you had written you have edited it to be $B_n = \{q \leq 1/n \}$

Comment: and which line do you mean by first line?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the comment. By first line I mean $Q(B_n) = \int_{B_n}q d\mu$. Hence if $\mu(B_n)=0$, $Q(B_n)=0$. When $\mu(B_n)>0$, $Q(B_n) \le -\mu(B_n)/n$. Now with the change $B_n= \{x : q(x) \le -1/n\}$, $Q(B_n) \le -\mu(B_n)/n$ always holds.

Comment: Okay thank you and sorry I dont get why $Q(B_n)=0$ follows directly from $\mu(B_n)=0$ given that $Q(B_n)=\int_{B_n}q d\mu$. Can you explain that?

Comment: Sure! This is just a result of the definition of the integral. If $\mu(A)=0$, then $\int_A f d\mu =0$. If $f$ is positive, $\int_A f d\mu = \sup\{ \int_A s d\mu, \; s \le f ,\; s \mbox{ a simple function } \}$. Since for any simple function $s \le f$, $\int_A s d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(A \cap A_i) =0$, as a result of $\mu(A)=0 \implies \mu(A \cap A_i) =0$. As such  $\sup\{ \int_A s d\mu, \; s \le f ,\; s \mbox{ a simple function } \}=0$. You can say the same thing for negative $f$, and the result then follows for any $f=f^+ - f^-$.